# C#でのShell.Applicationで「shell:」と変数をつなげるとパスが取得できない

Tags: c#

お世話になります。  
　この間の続きみたいな感じです。

Shell.ApplicationのNamespaceの引数に「"shell:"+フォルダ名」とすると、例外エラーが起きてしまうようです。  
　これは、こういう仕様なのか、それとも何か書き方が悪いのか、教えていただけると幸いです。  
　下記がサンプルコードになります。

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MainClass{
public static void Main(){
string FolderName = "Download";
var instanceType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
dynamic shell = Activator.CreateInstance(instanceType);
var folder = shell.Namespace("shell:"+FolderName);
string directory = folder.Self.Path;
Console.WriteLine(directory);
}
}
```

そして、エラーが下記になります。

ハンドルされていない例外: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: null 参照に対して実行時バインディングを実行することはできません  
   場所 CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )  
   場所 System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)  
   場所 MainClass.Main()

もし解決法等がありましたら、教えていただけると幸いです。  
　よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: "shell:Downloads" ('s'を付与)では、どうなりますか?

Comment: すみません。  
　単純なミスでしたね。  
　「Downloads」にしたら治りました。  
　ありがとうございました。